# How to change text display when checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, checkbox

I am making a form that will have checkboxes and entry text. When a checkbox is check, related text should appear adjacent to it. This is my current code, but it does not work:
HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="box1" onchange="showHide()"> Option 1
<div class="hid box1">
    <select name="option1">
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
     </select>
    Comments: <input type="text" name="option1Comment">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hid {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function showHide() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementByClassName(this);
    var text = document.getElementByClassName(this "hid");
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        text.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `getElementByClassName`

Comment: opt to use `querySelectors` to make things easier to read and understand

Comment: Please make sure to check the browser console for errors first. There is no `getElementByClassName`, the function is called getElement**s**ByClassName. Therefore you also need to grab the first element of the returned list: `var checkBox = document.getElementsByClassName("box1")[0];`

Comment: also areas to improve (unrelated): your if statement where you check whether the checkbox is checked does not require the `== true` and you can write an inline if in fact.

Comment: I wanted to try to avoid indices which is why I made 2 different classes to select with. The "hid" class is applied to any div that I want to remain hidden until checked and then the second class pairs the div with a checkbox of the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you should fix in your code.

First, you could change the function call on the `<input>` from
`onchange="showHide()"` to `onchange="showHide(this)"`

Then, you could fix the syntax of `getElementByClassName` on your function or change it to [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get just the one `Node` you want.

After that you could do something like this to hide or show your `<div>`:

```
function showHide(element) {
    let checkboxClass = element.classList[0];
    let div = document.querySelector("div.hid." + checkboxClass);
    div.style.display = (element.checked) ? "block" : "none";
}
```

Comment: for personal curiosity, why not use `querySelectors` to make things easier?

Comment: @RohanBhangui I just tried following what OP was doing. Personally, in this case, it should use `querySelector("div.hid")` which is way better to read and understand. I might edit the answer with it :)

Comment: What is querySelector?

Comment: @rkafds think of css selectors style but for js: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: I added what @RohanBhangui said with a link to the MDN site.

Comment: @FF- rkafds could also use toggling classes instead of directly changing style properties on the DOM

Comment: @RohanBhangui OP could do that, but it would lose the magic one-liner :), since it would mean to change the check to `if (element.checked) { div.classList.remove("hid"); } else { div.classList.add("hid"); }`

Comment: @FF- fair enough :P (technically you could still run it as one liner but it would just be less readable)

Comment: So this is what I have: `function showHide(element) {
 let div = document.querySelector("div.hid");
 div.style.display = (element.checked) ? "block" : "none";
 if (element.checked) { div.classList.remove("hid"); } else { div.classList.add("hid");
}`

Comment: You need to select one or the other. Right now you have both. Delete the line `if (element.checked) { div.classList.remove("hid"); } else { div.classList.add("hid"); }`

Comment: However, if I do this fix, only my first hid div shows up for any checkbox checked, not the one that corresponds to it.

Comment: That's because of the selector used. Instead of `div.hid`, use `document.querySelector("div.hid.box1");`

Comment: Could I put `document.querySelector("div.hid.element");` to use the same class as the checkbox that was selected? That way it is usable on all checkboxes.

Comment: I'm going to edit the anwser to meet that requirement.